# Localization for security identity in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, sid

I was looking to implement a named pipe for service/client communication in .NET and came across [this code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSNamedPipeCommunication-33b2485c/view/SourceCode) that, while initializing server side of the pipe had to set up a security descriptor for the pipe. They did it this way:

```
PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();

// Allow Everyone read and write access to the pipe.
pipeSecurity.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("Authenticated Users",
    PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

// Allow the Administrators group full access to the pipe.
pipeSecurity.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("Administrators",
    PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

But I'm looking at it, and I'm concerned about specifying SIDs as strings, or `Authenticated Users` and `Administrators` parts. What is the guarantee that they will be called that, say, in Chinese or some other language?

Comment: OK. I confirmed it myself. It seems to work.

Comment: You should consider splitting this up into a proper question/answer pair.

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: Answer extracted. Will delete upon OP's post or on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Extracted from OP's original question)

I came up with this alternative:

```
PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();

// Allow Everyone read and write access to the pipe.
pipeSecurity.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(
    "Authenticated Users",
    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null),   
    PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

// Allow the Administrators group full access to the pipe.
pipeSecurity.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(
    "Administrators",
    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null),   
    PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, there is no overload that takes the string and the `SecurityIdentifier`, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipeaccessrule.pipeaccessrule(v=vs.110).aspx). Remove the string literals `"Authenticated Users"` and `"Administrators"`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use WellKnownSidType enum to get sid and translate into IdentityReference:

```
        var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);
        var everyone = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
        security.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(everyone, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

Comment: "Everyone" is not a great idea. You probably want at least `WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid`. Is there a particular reason you use `WorldSid` (Everyone) other than paranoia that it might not work?

Comment: Exactly! Changed.

Comment: Everyone is a good idea when you running into unknown security problems, using it allows you to pass a sanity test to ensure you code is working after which you can narrow down what level of security is really needed.