# C# Named Pipe Server protected by AD security group

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using the following code in my class's ctor to create a named pipe in C#.

```
PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("testADgroup", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance | PipeAccessRights.ChangePermissions, AccessControlType.Allow));
pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 16, 
PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 1024, 1024, ps);
streamReader = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
serverThread = new Thread(this.serviceThread);
```

When the pipe is up, I use these powershell commands to try to open the pipe

```
$npipeClient = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream("testPipe")
$npipeClient.Connect()
```

This is the error that I get

```
Exception calling "Connect" with "0" argument(s): "Access to the path is denied."
At line:1 char:1
+ $npipeClient.Connect()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
```

If I change the C# code to have `PipeAccessRule` to use the Users group instead, it works fine.  However, I want to restrict access to the named pipe based on membership of an AD security group.

Can someone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong, or if perhaps the type of named pipe implementation that I'm using is not capable of utilizing AD group in the PipeAccessRule.
Thanks!

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156393(v=vs.110).aspx) for PipeAccessRule indicate that the first parameter is a Username, not a group name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890860/localization-for-security-identity-in-net

Comment: `new PipeAccessRule(new NTAccount("DOMAIN","testADGroup"),PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance | PipeAccessRights.ChangePermissions, AccessControlType.Allow)`